# Different program results depending on where variable is defined

Tags: c++, memory

I'm not too sure how to state this question, since I'm unable to produce a minimum working example of what is occurring. However, I'll try and give a high level sketch of what is going on to see if anyone knows what ***type of error*** this could be (and not necessarily what is directly causing the error itself).

The issue I'm facing is that I have a program that is producing different results depending on whether I define a particular variable as a class variable, or as a variable local to a class function.

As an example, let's assume I have the following class:

```
class DataProcessor{
    public:
        ...
        void iterate();
        std::unordered_map<size_t, Point3d> process_data(const std::vector<Point3d> &input_data);
        ...
    
    private:
        ...
        std::vector<Point3d> input_data_;
        std::unordered_map<size_t, Point3d> processed_data_;
        bool initialized_;
        ...
};
```

This class has an `iterate()` function that is called whenever new data arrives:

```
 void DataProcessor::iterate() {
   
    // Doing some stuff here
 
    if(initialized_) {

        processed_data_= process_data(input_data_);
        
        // Doing something with processed_data_

        processed_data_.clear();
    }

    // Doing something else here
}
```

Within the `iterate()` function, the `process_data()` function is called, that receives `input_data_`, and outputs its results to `processed_data_`. Finally, just before going out of the block of code in the `if` statement scope, `processed_data_` is cleared with `processed_data_.clear()`. Furthermore, this is the only place in the program where `processed_data_` is used.

When running my program in the above form it produces "bad" results (that is, the program doesn't crash, but the final output results are undesirable).

However, if I instead create a local variable in the `iterate()` function called `processed_data` (and delete the class variable `processed_data_`), as follows:

```
void DataProcessor::iterate() {
   
    // Doing some stuff here
 
    if(initialized_) {

        std::unordered_map<size_t, Point3d> processed_data = process_data(input_data_);
        
        // Doing something with processed_data
    }

    // Doing something else here
}
```

Then it produces "good". However, I would have thought that the results produced by each version of the `iterate()` function would be identical, since the only place where `processed_data_` or `processed_data` is being used is inside the `if` block.

I understand that this might not aid users who are looking to help me too much in finding a *direct* solution to my problem. But I was wondering if anyone might know what ***type of problem*** this could be, so that I might be able to use some tools such as `valgrind`, or one of the many `sanitizers` available in `gcc` and `clang`.

---

Running the program with `valgrind` brings up memory leak information, but there aren't any reported *memory errors*:

```
==14704== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14704==     in use at exit: 474,043 bytes in 3,799 blocks
==14704==   total heap usage: 1,589,224 allocs, 1,585,425 frees, 541,188,048 bytes allocated
==14704==
==14704== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14704==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14704==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14704==      possibly lost: 5,160 bytes in 25 blocks
==14704==    still reachable: 468,883 bytes in 3,774 blocks
==14704==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==14704==                         newarray           : 4,632 bytes in 19 blocks
==14704==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14704== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14704==
==14704== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==14704== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I would have thought that memory leaks wouldn't cause any of the strange above-mentioned behavior, but memory errors could. However, with `valgrind` telling me that no memory errors occurred it's left me scratching my head a bit. I'm wondering if there could be any other tools I could use to try and dig deeper into this potential memory error issue.

Comment: Is this program multi-threaded? Is there someone else from a different function accessing `processed_data_` potentially at the same time? what is processed_data and does `clear` do the same thing as reconstructing it?

Comment: This program is single-threaded, and `clear()` is the default clear function that is provided by `std::unordered_map` that deletes all elements.

Comment: Does the `process_data` function refer to the `processed_data_` member variable?  It would be unfriendly for you to modify the map, and then replace it with whatever the function returns.

Comment: Nope, the `process_data()` function doesn't refer to the `processed_data_` member variable.

Comment: If deleting the member variable from the class and adding a declaration just before using it in iterate produces different results then the variable can't be used anywhere else or it wouldn't compile.  If it is always cleared immediately after using it in iterate then it can't be because something was left in it from a previous iteration.  So the only thing left is memory corruption - something is modifying the memory of the map without accessing it via the variable.  Unfortunately, that requires seeing all the code because it could happen anywhere after the class object is created.

Comment: Hi @JerryJeremiah, I'm thinking along those same lines. However, when I run valgrind with `valgrind ./myprogram`, it returns memory leak information, but doesn't say that any memory errors occurred. I would have thought that memory leaks wouldn't cause such behavior, but memory errors could. However, with valgrind telling me that no memory errors occurred it's left me scratching my head a bit. Do you know of any other tools I could use to try and dig deeper into this potential memory error issue?

Comment: It seems that process_data is not pure, but not only does it cause side-effects, but also relies on some state; possibly on `processed_data_` (the data member) being something (empty?). If you're 100% sure that's not the case (and you can remove `processed_data_` member from the class when using your second version of code) then it seems like a memory corruption. But I wonder: are you 100% sure it's the case, including performing a clean build etc.? Maybe it's not the code itself, but some sort of linking error or similar?

Comment: Provide reproductible samples (as expected by the site)... else we just blindly do hypothesis...

Comment: Hi @alagner, I make sure that I clear out `processed_data_` at the end of the `if` statement block, and it's not used after that. With the second version of the code (with the local `processed_data` variable), I also delete the `processed_data_` member variable to ensure it doesn't have any effect. Regarding a clean build, I've tried clean builds (i.e. deleted the build folder) with `clang++ 10.0.0` and `g++ 10.3.0`, and get the same results.

Comment: @Jarod42, creating a reproducible example would be quite difficult as there is a lot of code above `process_data()` that is required for it to work, hence why I'm more asking for tools or methods to identify the type of error, instead of finding a direct solution.

Comment: You might have UB, which behave differently with *unrelated* changes (as out of bound access which override next member...).